# Printing all the nodes in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to print 7 items from a linked list, and add a comma after each one (not including the last one).  However, it is only printing one of the nodes.

Here is the method I have so far.

```
public String forwards() {
    ListNode n = head;
    String result = n + " ";
    if (n.next != null) {
        result = n.name.toString() + ", ";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `While`  ?????????????

Comment: You are not iterating over the LL. Also you need to do `result = result + ..`

Comment: My friend, please give some times to your code before posting to so one by one (mentioning about last post).... sorry if I am harsh

Comment: again the same mistake. n.next != null . Wil skip the last element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *loop* over the linked list to traverse it, otherwise only the single element will get printed. This is what I mean:

```
public String forwards() {

    if (head == null)
        return "";

    ListNode n = head;
    String result = n.name;
    n = n.next;

    while (n != null) {
        result += ", " + n.name;
        n = n.next;
    }

    return result;

}
```

The above takes into consideration the edge cases: empty list, single-element list, and prints the value of each node separated by a comma, except for the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
public String forwards() {
    ListNode n = head;
    String result = "";
    while (n != null) {
        result += n.name.toString() + ", ";
        n = n.next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: change : while (n.next != null) to while (n!= null). Else, it will skip the last element.

Comment: Oh thanks for that! We learned our lesson from his last post haha.